# Problem in migrating multiple project tables into one database using logical separation with alembic migrations

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I have two web services with different packages both using flask-sqlalchemy, postgres, alembic. I want to migrate both services in one database using logical separation(means define different schemes under one database),I am not able to migrate both the services using logical separation e.g if i migrate first service then second service gives alembic revision not found error.I have searched everywhere but still stuck at same problem.Please someone help?